# An infinite product of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $x_{1}=\sqrt{2}$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{2x_{n}}{x_{n}+1}}$. Find the value of:
\begin{align} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty }x_{n} \end{align}

Comment: Useful [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85311/8581)

Comment: Your title is not appropriate, since it suggests that there are infinitely many sequences being considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach to this problem is to start by showing $$\frac{1}{x_n} = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$
Then, you'll have $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty x_n = \frac{1}{\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)}$$
This can be evaluated using [Viète's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Vi.C3.A8te.27s_infinite_product) which tells us that $$\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty \cos\left(\frac{\pi/2}{2^{n}}\right) = \frac{\sin(\pi/2)}{\pi/2}=\frac{2}{\pi}$$
(and the original infinite product is then equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$)

---

A different approach tackles the product directly by showing that
$$\prod_{k=1}^n x_k = 2^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$
The desired infinite product is then equal to the limit of this expression as $n$ tends to infinity; which can be easily shown to be equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Well done Peter.